# Laravel when I reading an HTML file in the public directory does not read the JS files next to HTML file in public

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

I used Krpano tools software for virtual tours web in Laravel. The software outputs the files HTML and JS and many folders for a run virtual tours. 
When uploading[image] zip this outputs and upload from the web in Laravel

[image]

When I upload this zip output to the public folder from the form in blade and controller.When I want to save it Zip extract in the controller and saves it to the public directory. When I call, the files are not read. Because Java Script's path is defined in public. This is going to be repeated for hundreds of outputs virtual tour. But because Js file is in the public folder doesn't read it in the blade file. because does not exist in the view directory

Comment: you can try `{{ asset('tour.js') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your .htaccess is not referring vtour folder as root folder than this will not work

```
{{ asset('tour.js') }}
```

because the system will assume that tour.js is placed in root folder. You can try this

```
{{ asset('upload/vtour/tour.js') }}
```

Comment: Edit: If you .htaccess is not referring vtour folder as root folder than this will not work